# XML inserting nodes twice in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table with Questions and a table with answers. Right now my tables of answer has a Question_ID and the answers that go with that question, like:

```
    Question_ID    Answer_Text
         1            true
         1            false
         2            blue
         2            brown
         2            green
```

This is an example of my Question table:

```
    Question_ID     Question_Text
         1          Are you happy?
         2          What color are your eyes?
```

I'm am trying to create a statement so an XML FILE gets read into SQL server and inserts the questions and answers to those questions into the two seperate tables.

Here is my XML:

```
     <Questions>
<Question>

       <QuestionText>Is today good?</QuestionText>
       <QuestionType>1</QuestionType>
       <QuestionaireID>2</QuestionaireID>
       <Filter>31</Filter>
       <PossibleAnswers>
              <PossibleAnswer>
                     <Value>True</Value>
                     <RequiresExplanation>1</RequiresExplanation>
                     <ReviewRequire>t</ReviewRequire>
              </PossibleAnswer>
              <PossibleAnswer>
                     <Value>False</Value>
                       <RequiresExplanation>1</RequiresExplanation>
                     <ReviewRequire>f</ReviewRequire>
              </PossibleAnswer>
       </PossibleAnswers>
</Question>
<Question>
       <QuestionText>How are you today?</QuestionText>
       <QuestionType>1</QuestionType>
       <QuestionaireID>2</QuestionaireID>
         <Filter>127</Filter>
       <PossibleAnswers>
              <PossibleAnswer>
                     <Value>Great</Value>
                      <RequiresExplanation>1</RequiresExplanation>
                     <ReviewRequire>t</ReviewRequire>
              </PossibleAnswer>
              <PossibleAnswer>
                     <Value>Good</Value>
                        <RequiresExplanation>1</RequiresExplanation>
                     <ReviewRequire>t</ReviewRequire>
              </PossibleAnswer>
              <PossibleAnswer>
                     <Value>Bad</Value>
                       <RequiresExplanation>1</RequiresExplanation>
                     <ReviewRequire>t</ReviewRequire>
              </PossibleAnswer>
       </PossibleAnswers>
</Question>
</Questions>
```

And here is my SQL code:

```
     DECLARE @QuestionText varchar(200)
DECLARE @Value varchar(400)
DECLARE @RequiresExplanation int
DECLARE @QuestionType bigint
DECLARE @Questionaire_ID bigint
DECLARE @Filter bigint
DECLARE @ReviewRequired char(1)
DECLARE @LAST_Question varchar(200) = ''
DECLARE @newQuestion_ID bigint

--SET UP A CURSOR to walk through the uploaded XML table
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL for 
       SELECT
              QuestionText =  XTbl.value('(../../QuestionText)[1]', 'varchar(200)'),
              QuestionType =  XTbl.value('(../../QuestionType)[1]', 'bigint'),
              Questionaire_ID =  XTbl.value('(../../QuestionaireID)[1]', 'bigint'),
              Filter =  XTbl.value('(../../Filter)[1]', 'bigint'),
              Value = XTbl.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(400)'),
              RequiresExplanation = XTbl.value('(RequiresExplanation)[1]', 'int'),
              ReviewRequired =  XTbl.value('(ReviewRequire)[1]', 'char(1)')
from (
select cast(x as XML)
from openrowset(
bulk 'C:\sqlXML.xml',
single_blob) as T(x)
    )
as T(x)
cross apply     x.nodes('/Questions/Question/PossibleAnswers/PossibleAnswer') AS XD(XTbl)

-- open the cursor
open cur 

 -- fetch the first row

fetch next from cur into        
                                @QuestionText,
                                @QuestionType,
                                @Questionaire_ID,
                                @Filter,
                                @Value,
                                @RequiresExplanation,                           
                                @ReviewRequired







-- process each view we want to cache
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 



       IF @LAST_Question <> @QuestionText
       BEGIN
       insert into [TempDataBase].[dbo].TestQuestion
       (QuestionType, Question_Text, Questionaire_ID, Filter)
       VALUES
       (@QuestionType, @QuestionText, @Questionaire_ID,@Filter)

              --insert to create a question
              --scope_identity to get @Q_ID

     END

     print 'Question'
        select @newQuestion_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()




       --INSERT your possible answers
       INSERT INTO [TempDataBase].[dbo].TestPossible
              (Q_ID,      Expl, Rev, P_A_T, QType)
              VALUES
              (@newQuestion_ID,  @RequiresExplanation, @ReviewRequired, @Value,               @QuestionType)
        print 'Answer'
       -- fetch the first row

       fetch next from cur into                     

                               @QuestionText,
                                @QuestionType,
                                @Questionaire_ID,
                                @Filter,
                                @Value,
                                @RequiresExplanation,                           
                                @ReviewRequired


END
```

The problem is that each question is being inserted twice and each answer has a different Question_ID instead of how I described in my example tables. Is there a way to do this? I've tried rearranging some things, or even just inserting the questions by themselves but they are still being inserted multiple times.

Comment: Offhand, I'd say the "possible answer" cross apply is causing the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Last_Question wasn't ever set to the current question so it was performing the loop twice